# Hiding/encrypting an external hdd partition in a non-destructive way ?

Tags: hard-drive, security, encryption

i have an external hdd with personal info like bank details personal projects etc. I have 2 partitions, one for my personal stuff and one for casual stuff. 
I tried truecrypt, but when the disk is plugged, the encrypted partitions appear as unformatted drives, and anyone will be tempted to format it, thus destroying all data.

I am looking for a way to make only the casual partition visible on any computer it is plugged in.

Comment: Why do other people have access to your computer while your personal external hdd is connected to the computer?  The simple solution would be use Bitlocker instead.

Comment: "my personal external hdd" might not be always connected to my computer. in fact, most of the time i have to lend it to my friends to transfer stuff across computers. Unfortunately, Bitlocker doesn't prevent directory listing.

Comment: Simple solution to that problem.  Use Bitlocker and have a TrueCrypt container be the only thing that exists on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create only one non-encrypted partition and then to create a truecrypt volume on it: when not mounted it will look like a normal (big) file inside, [just like a any other file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt#Identifying_TrueCrypt_volumes)